# Nesting byobu sessions

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

Is there a working solution for having a nested byobu, or byobu-screen sessions?

It would need to have a way to specify different keybindings for the outer and the inner windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily nest [Byobu](http://byobu.org) sessions.  The F-key short cuts will only work in the outer most Byobu, though.  To pass control commands to the inner, nested sessions, you simply need to hit the control sequence multiple times.  So you'll need to learn the Tmux commands.

For instance, to move to the next window in the inner session, do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>

You can find more information at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/271837/how-to-use-byobu-keybindings-in-a-nested-remote-session

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.*

Answer (score 0):

the [Dustin](https://superuser.com/users/115303/dustin-kirkland) is the developer of [byobu](https://www.byobu.org) and it is very ugly to answer after him.

but I solved my problem with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>. it disables outer byubo keybinding.